# Splitting an array into multi dimensional array chunks

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, logic

I was supposed to

> "Write a function that splits an array (first argument) into groups
>   the length of size (second argument) and return them as a
>   two-dimensional array."

Unfortunately, I could not figure it out thus I checked the code solution. The problem is I don't understand *why* this conditional statement is used: `if (a % size !== size - 1)`

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {

      var temp = [];
      var result = [];

      for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
        if (a % size !== size - 1)
          temp.push(arr[a]);
        else {
          temp.push(arr[a]);
          result.push(temp);
          temp = [];
        }
      }

      if (temp.length !== 0)
        result.push(temp);
      return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That conditional statement checks if the current index (`a`) modulo the size of the chunks (`size`) is not equal to `size - 1`. The purpose of this is to check, using the index, if a new chunk should be created or not.